# CSS file is not connecting in an express app

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

When running my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));    
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Serving on port ${port}`)
})
```

this is my index.html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Testing CSS</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

then I can not observe the changes of CSS file on the page. But when I open the HTML file with live serever I can see the CSS changes why is this happening.

When I am running my app.js file css is not connecting. But when I open the HTML file with live server CSS file is connecting. What is the reason behind this ??

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

include this in your app.js create a folder called public and put the style.css in your public directory.
your code would be

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express();
    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))


    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //<-here



    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));    
    });
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Serving on port ${port}`)
    })
```